# How can i redirect after i use transaction and throw new \Exception('Error')

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, controller, laravel-5.4

How can i redirect after i use transaction and  throw new \Exception('Error'); from my code below when i've an error it stop at  else{throw new \Exception('Error');}  and my if($errors) not working

is their anyway to redirect after throw new \Exception() ?

```
$errors = false;
    DB::transaction(function () use ($count,$request,$a,$errors) {
        for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            $warehouse_products_sell = New Warehouse_products_sell;
            $id_w = $request->input('idw');
            $id_c = $request->get('id_c')[$i];
            $id_p = $request->get('id_p')[$i];
            $qty = $request->input('quantity_box')[$i];
            $price = $request->input('price')[$i];
            $available = $this->check_stock($id_w, $id_p, $qty);
          if($available > 0){

            $warehouse_products_sell->save();
          }else{

            echo "error";
            $errors = true;
            throw new \Exception('Error');
          }
        }
    });
    if ($errors) {
       return redirect('URL');
    }else{
        return 'x';
    }
```

Comment: catch it then.. rtm http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.catch.php

Comment: @LawrenceCherone i try to catch but if i've  3 correct data and 1 wrong data it will save 3 data i want to reject all not sure im do the right thing ill try it again .

Comment: then use break in the catch section.

Comment: ok thanks ill try it now @LawrenceCherone

Comment: or wrap `DB::transaction` in try catch not just the Exception

Comment: cloud you please give me some expample? @LawrenceCherone

Comment: Here is an example, https://3v4l.org/HsaWr, wont give it all away ;p

Comment: thank its work  @LawrenceCherone

Answer (score 1):

Don't abuse database transactions for something you can check yourself without a database transaction:

```
// Step 1. Check all products
$products = [];
for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $warehouse_products_sell = New Warehouse_products_sell;
    $id_w = $request->input('idw');
    $id_c = $request->get('id_c')[$i];
    $id_p = $request->get('id_p')[$i];
    $qty = $request->input('quantity_box')[$i];
    $price = $request->input('price')[$i];
    $available = $this->check_stock($id_w, $id_p, $qty);
    if ($available <= 0){
        throw new \Exception(sprintf('Not enough stock for %s/%s (stock=%d, requested=%d)', $id_w, $id_p, $available, $qty));
    }
    $products[] = $warehouse_products_sell
}

// Step 2. All checks have passed, save data to database
DB::transaction(function () use ($products) {
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $product->save();
    }
});
```